# I've not received my last pay check from my contracting firm. What should I do?

Tags: salary, recruitment, human-resources, contracting

I am in a bit of a pickle.  I took a position with a major corporation about a month ago.  I really like the company, the people I work with and the managers.  I am very happy with my current work environment.

Technically, however, I am not hired by this corporation.  Instead, I was hired through a contractual recruiting firm and I have a one year contract.  Assuming my managers like me, there is a very "good chance" that I will be directly hired in 3-6 months.  From what I gather this is typical practice within this industry.

My problem is that my first three pay checks (we are are paid weekly) have appeared without any trouble.  The first one was received by mail and the last two by direct deposit.  This past Friday, my direct deposit didn't show up.  It's also worth mentioning that this firm uses ADP for payroll.  I can log into my ADP Portal account and see all four pay stubs, so I should have been paid this past Friday.

Monday, I sent an email to my... *handler* and she mentioned to get back in touch with her on Wednesday (yesterday) if my check hadn't deposited.  It didn't and I emailed her, though she has yet to respond.

My next plan of action is to email my manager within the recruiting firm by mid-day today if I don't hear from my handler this morning.  I think this is the best next step.  Still, I want to have a good game plan in case my last check doesn't post tomorrow, along with the check that I am due at that time.

I really like this company and I hope that I get brought on full time in 3-6 months.  However, I can't work for free.  What should I do?

Comment: Comments on why this is being marked to close?  This is really a tough place to be in.  If I was a direct hire, and a company had these issues, I'd starting considering looking for another job in 3-6 months if this kept up.  But, since it's not the companies fault, and the recruiting firm, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: From the FAQ: _What questions are off topic here?

"I need advice on...", "What should I do?", or "Which job should I take?"_ Questions seeking advice are off topic. Perhaps an edit to make it less advice seeking?

Comment: Thank you, Bmo.  I see now.  Yes, I've used this site form time to time over the past few years, but not a lot.  I think these questions at one point (in the earlier days) were appropriate.

Comment: FYI, regarding the closure mark, I can't direct this to "HR".  I know this sound odd, but I can't find a single HR contact and I've always been told to get in contact with my direct handler, or my manager within the firm, for assistance.  I know this is advice, but I don't have very many people to reach out to.

Comment: You should go ahead and check this with the payroll department.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a bank glitch.  It's almost certainly not a deliberate screwup on the part of the HR company you're working with or the place you work.

I have handled this kind of trouble before. You need to go, in person, to a branch of the bank where you do business. You need to ask to see a senior manager or VP. (I don't think most tellers know what to do about this.) Bring along as many ADP pay stubs as you have, or go onto your ADP account and print them out. Definitely bring the one for the missing payment.

It is very important indeed to have the date the direct deposit was supposed to occur, the exact amount, and any other identifying information you can offer.

Say to the bank person, "Do you have about a half-hour? I have a problem.Please help me. A direct payroll deposit of mine seems to be lost."

The name of the bank department that can track down this kind of trouble is the "ACH transfer department" or something like that. They usually can find a direct deposit that didn't make it into the right account. Your local bank person will know how to get in touch with them.

Don't delay!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there is a glitch some where - either with your recruiting company or with your bank. I would send a follow up email to your handler letting her know that it hasn't been deposited and copy your manager. I'd confirm that ADP has your correct bank routing information. I would also follow up with your bank to see if they can help.

Comment: I hadn't thought about contacting the bank. I'll try that too.